The DML statement cannot have any enabled triggers if the statement contains an OUTPUT clause without INTO clause
In a Blazor Server App I used a TSQL script to backup/log a recordset before edit and update. But with .NET 8 this works no more, how can i change this in TSQL itself (not in Blazor)?
ERROR:


Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: "Could not save changes because the
target table has database triggers.
SqlException: The target table 'T' of the DML statement cannot have any enabled triggers if the statement contains an OUTPUT clause without INTO clause.
```sql
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[T]
ON [dbo].[T]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS 
BEGIN   
    INSERT INTO dbo.T_Log([IdOri],  [UserLogIn],    [Name]) 
                    SELECT  i.[Id], i.[UserLogIn],  i.[Name]

    FROM inserted i                 
END
```


        This is the Blazor.razor Code: 
        
            public async Task SaveTicket()
            {
                // Get the current user
                if (authenticationStateTask != null)
                {
                    var user = (await authenticationStateTask).User;
                    if (user.Identity != null)
                    {
                        UserIdentityName = user.Identity.Name ?? "";
                    }
                }
                SelectedUser.Modified = DateTime.Now;
                SelectedUser.ModifiedBy = UserIdentityName;
        
                // Update the selected Help Desk Ticket
                //var result = await @Service.UpdateEmployeesAsync(SelectedTicket);
                var result = @Service.UpdateUserLogInAsync(SelectedUser);
        
                // Close the Edit dialog
                this.EditDialogVisibility = false;
                //gridObj.Refresh();
                await Task.Delay(300);
                FirmaUserLogInDataSetService2 = await Service.GetTaskFirmaUserLogInDataSetAsync(UserIdentityName);
            }
        
        And the Blazor.cs Code: 
                //2 edit/update
                public Task<bool> UpdateUserLogInAsync(FirmaUserLogInDataSet _UserLogInDataSet)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var IstUserLogInDataSet =
                        _context.FirmaUserLogInDataSet
                        .Where(x => x.Id == _UserLogInDataSet.Id)
                        .FirstOrDefault();
                        if (IstUserLogInDataSet != null)
                        {
                            IstUserLogInDataSet.AktivDs = _UserLogInDataSet.AktivDs;
                        IstUserLogInDataSet.Name = _UserLogInDataSet.Name;
    
    // etc ...
                _context.SaveChanges();
            }
            else
            {
                return Task.FromResult(false);
            }
            return Task.FromResult(true);
        }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    DetachAllEntities();
    throw;
        }
    }


The problem appears to more likely be your Blazor code, not the T-SQL. Show us the code you are using that is performing the DML operation.

Betting 200$ on @Charlieface
